# Certificate Template Information from AD

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, certificate

How is it possible to retrieve the certificate template's HAsh algorithm and name from the active directory using C#? In addition, is it possible to find an OIDGroup and name from an Oid?

Comment: I had a quick look - I can't see any ADSI API for working with X.509 certificates. I might suggest looking at WMI. If the certificate is stored as an object (i.e. a `cn=`) then you might be able to get a `DirectoryEntry` directly and see if it's stored in a known format, then dump and examine it manually.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried cn=certificate templates and got a DirectoryEntry object and was able to extract the template properties. But, I do not see the properties for hash algorithm and name.